# What is the difference between "either...or.." and "not only.. but also"?

Tags: difference, conjunctions

What is the difference between "either...or.." and "not only.. but also"?

I'm making many mistakes about them when I'm solving a conjuncture question. They both seem to match the sentences.

Comment: Pretty obviously, the difference between (1) *either A or B* and (2) *not only A but also B* is that (1) refers to ***only one thing** (we don't know/care **which** of A or B it is)*. Whereas (2) refers to ***both of them*** - with the added implication that although A might have been "expected", it's perhaps surprising that B is included as well (or that one might have expected *either* or *neither* of them, but certainly not *both*).

Comment: _either ... or_ is a kind of OR. _not only ... but also..._ is a kind of AND.